# Разобрать html страницу в php

Tags: curl, php, html, парсер

Пишу парсер, использую curl. Функция curl_exec возвращает строку с html кодом страницы. Как вынуть из этого кода теги, их атрибуты и их содержимое? Пробую DOMDocument, но он возвращает кучу предупреждений (Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() и т.д.)
Может есть другой вариант распарсить код?

Короче решение найдено в том, чтобы создавать объект Simple html dom. Оказалось что в него можно передать строку с html-кодом, и он создаст объект, к которому уже можно применять все методы обработки кода!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так может стоит присмотреться к этим предупреждениям и попытаться понять их смысл? И если они связаны с кривой разметкой (что сейчас сплошь и рядом), например, то просто игнорировать ошибки этого типа, на то есть `libxml_*()`. Ну или [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Да, я тоже думаю на кривую разметку.
file_get_html не годится. Как я понял сервер быстро понимает, что его парсят и блокирует такие запросы.
В .htaccess указал
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag display_startup_errors off
но тогда вообще ничего не возвращается.

libxml_*() а для чего это? Более простым способом разве нельзя отключить предупреждения?

Comment: Можно, конечно, отключить `E_WARNING` в принципе, но... в общем, сам так не делаю и никому не советую :) А с помощью [libxml_](http://php.ru/manual/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.html) можно управлять ошибками и предупреждениями только парсинга, не затрагивая все остальные.

Comment: Вызвал такой метод $doc->saveHTML(); и вроде пошло дело. Выводит документ, если написать echo $doc; только в корявой кодировке (ÑÑÐ±)

P.S. А, это он обратно строку сделал. Только кодировку испортил. Блин. Как же распарсить, если корявая разметка???

Comment: Сложно понять по трём символам, но это похоже на `UTF8<->cp1252`. Общий совет: никогда не забывать про чарсет из HTTP-ответа. Если в HTML тоже есть чарсет, и он другой - отрывать руки тем "вебмастерам", но пробовать придётся оба.

Comment: Что-то я не понял. В html не надо мета чарсет указывать?

Остается парсить регулярками?!

Comment: Чарсет в HTML указывать нужно потому, что если документ рассматривается вне HTTP-контекста (например, страницу сохранили на диск и открывают автономно), у нас просто нет другой информации о кодировке этого самого документа. В идеале этот чарсет должен совпадать с тем, что отдаётся в HTTP-заголовках. Если это не так, то для корректного преобразования документа из его чарсета в нужный (например, если мете написано windows-1251, а в HTTP - KOI8-R) придётся пробовать оба варианта перекодировки (cp1251->utf8, koi8r->utf8) и смотреть, какой больше похож на правду.